# Searching for a Java layoutmanager which hides elements if space is getting short

Tags: java, swing, resize, layout-manager

I'm searching for a Java layoutmanager which is able to automatically hide (less important) elements, defined by me, if the user scales down the window size.

For example an icon in a row of a label and a JTextField, which is only there to visually enhance the form. If the user resizes the window to a minimum size, the icon should disappear to give the remaining space to the label and the textfield.

Regards

Comment: I've only read about it - never used it myself - but the Java grid bag constraints layout allows more control over what components get more screen space when window size changes.
A quick google search gave me this tutorial:
http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html
But it does kind of the opposite of what you want; when the screen gets bigger who gets more, as opposed to when the screen gets smaller who gets less...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is not enough space GBL will switch from preferredSize to minimumSize so possibly if you set a very small minimumSize for the less important components GBL will work for you. You could also add a componentListener and just rebuild the GUI by manually removing components or just switching into another view.

You could even build a 'mini' view button into the GUI that would automatically resize to smallest possible but maintain a sensible size instead of users having to faff around on their own breaking stuff in your carefully planned design :)

Comment: You're right. Setting minimumSize to (0,0) does the job. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Well, from my memories, it seems to me that a [GridBagLayout](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) will also hide less important items when size scales down.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own LayoutManager (which, of course, extends one of existing layout managers). It's rather funny, I had such experience when was developing with swing.